# Wordpress .htaccess redirection issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Recently, I moved from a static website to a WordPress made website. Everything works perfectly except one thing.

My company uses players to display content and the players call an url like this to get the content :

```
https://mysite.fr/#thecontentpage.html
```

This url is from the old website. As the new website is on WordPress now, the url is a more "classic" one :

```
https://mysite.fr/thecontentpage.html
```

The best solution would be to make the players calling the new url but it's impossible. So I thought about doing a redirection with the `.htaccess` but it doesn't work.

Here's my `.htaccess` :

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress

Redirect 301 https://mysite.fr/#thecontentpage.html https://mysite.fr/thecontentpage.html
```

Even with the redirection, when I call `https://mysite.fr/#thecontentpage.html` I land on the main page and not the page I want.
What can I do to have my redirection working ?

Comment: Most probably Wordpress rewrite rules catches your URL before your redirection, if you try placing the `Redirect` before `# BEGIN WordPress`, does it work?

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't work, still the same thing.

Comment: I think that the problem comes from the `#` sign. I have found an article and it seems that `#` has to be escaped: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76047/redirect-urls-with-a-in-htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't make the redirection in PHP or with the .htaccess, I just used Javascript to made the redirection.

I insert this script in the `header.php` file from my child theme :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = window.location.href;
    var racine = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/"));
    var page = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

    if(page == "#old_url.html"){
        document.location.href = racine + "/new_url.html";
    }
</script>
```

As this file is located in the child theme, I'm not bothered by the updates on the main theme. My problem is solved then !

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck here as the hashtag is never sent to the server since it's an in-page fragment.  It is only ever used by the browser.  Therefore the .htaccess file will never see it, and you can't write a rewrite against it.  So, you will have to come up with a unique way to redirect using JavaScript before WordPress loads.  Most likely you'll need an index.php page that handles redirects and then sends anything not caught in your rule straight through to WordPress.

**UPDATE**
As mentioned, you can't do it with "WordPress" as it won't work do to the server never getting the hash part.  You can, however, use JavaScript.  Place this code just inside your `<head>` tag:

```
<script>
    var $hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if( $hash.length > 0 ) {
        window.location = $hash;
    }
</script>
```

Clearly you will want to really alter this simple code to do more enhanced checking and validation so that example.com/#whatever doesn't try to redirect... but this is a start for you.  You could have an array of "whitelist" redirects and check `$hash` against that array... just a thought.

Comment: Yeah, in the end I figured it out. 
Now I need to find a way to do it in Wordpress, which is not that easy.